# How can I examine and edit an entity's properties from PropertyBuilder?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm writing a mapper to map data types between different databases.

When iterating through entities after they have been set by `OnModelCreating` I need to examine these entity property values that have previously been set by `HasColumnType` and `HasDefaultValueSql` in order to alter these settings in a generic way.

How can I read and change these properties?

I'm currently using this function as a first approach:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    foreach (IMutableProperty prop in entity.GetDeclaredProperties())
      if (prop.ClrType == _byteArrayType)
        modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).Property(prop.Name).HasColumnType("VARBINARY");
}
```

But that's not the best approach. I need to read (and alter) the original SQL value that has been set (e.g. `XMLType` data type or `SYSDATE` default value.)

Comment: Look for  `GetXyz` (and `SetXyz`) *extension* methods, e.g. `GetColumnType`, `GetDefaultValueSql` etc.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you! Would you like to rephrase it as an answer to my question? I would gladly like to vote for it.